# Click a button after automatically logging in a website

Tags: vba

I wrote a macro so I could fill a form and access a website automatically:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "EXAMPLE.COM"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
HTMLDoc.all.USER.Value = "USER1" 
HTMLDoc.all.USER.FireEvent ("onchange")
HTMLDoc.all.PASS.Value = "PASS"
HTMLDoc.all.PASS.FireEvent ("onchange")
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
  If MyHTML_Element.getAttribute("src") = "imagesrc.gif" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

After the page loads, I've been trying to get it to click another button with no luck. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: not enough of it i guess, will do @JohnSaunders

Comment: You also didn't tell us what doesn't work, and this is either VBA or VB.NET, not both.

Comment: From my experience, you need to be looking for the input tag associated with the button.

Comment: it is VBA, it does work so far, im trying to add more code so it will click another button after the loggin loads @JohnSaunders

Comment: @ThomasBeckSutton thats easy to do, in fact i already tried it and its not working as it is in the first step of the process wich is the login

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @ThomasBeckSutton in the code i posted, i search for tag "img" and then click that button if the attribute src is found. When the button is clicked, it takes the browser to a new page, im trying to click a button on this new page and tried the same method adding code right after the "EXIT FOR NEXT" but it is not working. I dont think the program recognizes when the browser refreshes after the login and thats why its not clicking the following button.

Comment: I've had that issue before. What I found was that the code was running before the webpage was fully loaded thus skipping the button it was supposed to click. To fix this I put a line of code in that forces the macro to pause for a determined length of time while the webpage finishes loading.

Comment: @ThomasBeckSutton ok that sounds smart, i guess im not that smart would you teach me how to do it, guide me trough it or something. Please.

Comment: nothing more to add guys :(? @ThomasBeckSutton

Comment: @JohnSaunders nothing more to add guys :(?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to pause your program so that it can wait for the webpage to load. There are multiple ways of doing this but this little line of code works wonders.

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```

Just copy and paste that into your code after the click even. This will wait for approximately 10 seconds. You can adjust the time as needed.

Comment: thanks for the suggest, tried this before but it does not work, even if i try to implement it before the application fills up the login form for example, it won't make it wait.

Comment: anything bro? been reading all over the place, couldnt find a solution